# Button not clickable - custom tableviewcell nib - swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a custom table view cell with a button that's meant to be pressable on the top right-hand side of the cell. When pressed, the button should display an action sheet.

However, whenever I try to press the button, the cell performs the actions in didSelectRow instead of presenting the action sheet. It's as if the button isn't pressable but it should be. Here's the class:

```
class BulletinPostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

//MARK : VARIABLES

var tapAction: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userProfilePicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bulletinImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var optionsButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func optionsPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    tapAction?(self)
}


func customInit(titleText: String, descriptionText: String, occupations: String){
    self.title.text = titleText
    self.descriptionTextView.text = descriptionText
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

}

And heres the view controller that's using the custom cell nib:

```
class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

//MARK : VARIABLES
var refHandle: UInt!
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var bulletin: Bulletin!
var bulletinArray = [Bulletin]()
var userObject: User!
let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
let messageViewController = MFMessageComposeViewController()
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!

//MARK : CUSTOM VARIABLES (FOR TRANSITION)
var uid: String = ""
var customTitle: String = ""
var customImage: String = ""
var customUserName: String = ""
var customOccupations: String = ""
var customTimeStamp: String = ""
var customDescription: String = ""
var customUserImage: String = ""
var customLink: String?
var floatingActionButton = ButtonWithImage(type: .custom)
var occupations: [String] = []

//MARK : ACTIONS
@IBAction func searchButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //-- create a search button and then present it
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    //-- set any properties (in this case, don't hide the nav bar and don't show the emoji keyboard option)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable

    //-- make this class the delegate and present the search
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    fetchBulletins()
    getCurrentUser()


    //-- set table view heights
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

    //-- creates the nib for bulletin posts
    let bulletinNib = UINib(nibName: "BulletinPostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(bulletinNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "newBulletinCell")

    tableView.reloadData()
}


func getCurrentUser(){
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid!)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, err) in
        if let dictionary = document?.data() {
            let user = User(dictionary: dictionary  as [String: AnyObject])
            user.id = document?.documentID
            self.userObject = user
        }
    }
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "selectedBulletinTransition" {
        if let selectedView = segue.destination as? SelectedBulletinViewController {
            selectedView.bulletin = bulletin
        }
    }
}


//MARK : CUSTOM ACTIONS
func fetchBulletins(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("bulletins").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error:\(err)")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                var dictionary = document.data()
                let bulletin = Bulletin(dictionary: dictionary as [String: AnyObject])
                bulletin.id = document.documentID
                self.bulletinArray.insert(bulletin, at: 0)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func showAlertForRow(bulletin: Bulletin) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alertController.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Report", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        print("complete")
    })))
    alertController.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Block", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        print("complete")
    })))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



// MARK : TABLE VIEW METHODS
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bulletinArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    bulletin = bulletinArray[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "selectedBulletinTransition", sender: self)
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let bulletin = self.bulletinArray[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newBulletinCell", for: indexPath) as! BulletinPostTableViewCell

    //-- set the properties for custom variables (title, description, occupations, image)
    self.customTitle = bulletin.bulletinTitle!
    self.customDescription = bulletin.bulletinDescription!
    self.customLink = bulletin.bulletinLink
    self.customUserName = bulletin.userName!

    cell.userNameLabel.text = bulletin.userName!

    if let userPicture = bulletin.userPhoto {
        let url = URL(string: userPicture)
        self.customUserImage = userPicture
        cell.userProfilePicture.kf.setImage(with: url)
        cell.userProfilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.userProfilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.userProfilePicture.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }

    //MARK: add action to cell button
    cell.tapAction = { (cell) in
        self.showAlertForRow(bulletin: bulletin)
    }

    //-- time
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, h:mm a"
    let dateStamp = dateFormatter.date(from: bulletin.date)
    cell.dateLabel.text = dateStamp!.timeAgoDisplay()

    //-- if theres no description, don't show it.
    if bulletin.bulletinDescription == nil || bulletin.bulletinDescription == ""{
        cell.descriptionTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    //-- sets the properties for the cell image.
    if bulletin.bulletinImage == nil {
        cell.bulletinImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
        cell.bulletinImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.customInit(titleText: bulletin.bulletinTitle!, descriptionText: String(bulletin.bulletinDescription!.prefix(180)) + "...", occupations: "")
        if let occupationArray = bulletin.occupations as? [String]{
            let occupationRepresentation = occupationArray.joined(separator: ", ")
        }
    } else {
        if let thisCustomImage = bulletin.bulletinImage {
            cell.customInit(titleText: bulletin.bulletinTitle!, descriptionText: String(bulletin.bulletinDescription!.prefix(90)) + "...", occupations: "")
            if let occupationArray = bulletin.occupations as? [String]{
                let occupationRepresentation = occupationArray.joined(separator: ", ")
            }
            self.customImage = thisCustomImage
            let url = URL(string: thisCustomImage)
            cell.bulletinImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
            cell.bulletinImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            cell.bulletinImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            cell.bulletinImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.bulletinImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }


    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Is the button inside the content view? How did it get there? How is it positioned? A button outside the bounds of its superview cannot be tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Check your storyboard. All Views between the UIButton and the ContentView of the Cell need to have their UserInteractionEnabled set to true.

Comment: And your button is connected to the @IBAction in ,your code?

Comment: Yeah its connected to it

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your table view cell selection capability.

```
tableView.allowsSelection = false
```